# Is running more epochs really a direct cause of overfitting?

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent

I've seen some comments in online articles/tutorials or [Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942612/why-too-many-epochs-will-cause-overfitting) which suggest that increasing number of epochs can result in overfitting. But my intuition tells me that there should be no direct relationship at all between number of epochs and overfitting. **So I'm looking for answer which explains if I'm right or wrong (or whatever's in between).**

Here's my reasoning though. To overfit, you need to have enough free parameters (I think this is called "capacity" in neural networks) in your model to generate a function which can replicate the sample data points. If you don't have enough free parameters, you'll never overfit. You might just underfit.

So really, if you don't have too many free parameters, you could run infinite epochs and never overfit. If you have too many free parameters, then yes, the more epochs you have the more likely it is that you get to a place where you're overfitting. But that's just because running more epochs revealed the root cause: too many free parameters. The real loss function doesn't care about how many epochs you run. It existed the moment you defined your model structure, before you ever even tried to do gradient descent on it.

In fact, I'd venture as far as to say: assuming you have the computational resources and time, you should always aim to run as many epochs as possible, because that will tell you whether your model is prone to overfitting. Your best model will be the one that provides great training and validation accuracy, no matter how many epochs you run it for.

**EDIT**
While reading more into this, I realise I forgot to take into account that you can arbitrarily vary the sample size as well. Given a fixed model, a smaller sample size is more prone to being overfit. And then that kind of makes me doubt my intuition above. Still happy to get an answer though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the amount of trainable parameters is small with respect to the size of your training set (and your training set is reasonably diverse) then running over the same data multiple times will not be that significant, since you will be learning some features about your problem, rather than just memorizing the training data set. The problem arises when the amount of parameters is comparable to your training data set size (or bigger), it is basically the same problem as with any machine learning technique that uses too many features. This is quite common if you use large layers with dense connections. To combat this overfitting problem there are lots of regularization techniques (dropout, L1 regularizer, constraining certain connections to be 0 or equal such as in CNN).

The problem is that might still be left with too many trainable parameters. A simple way to regularize even further is to have a small learning rate (i.e. don't learn too much from this particular example lest you memorize it) combined with monitoring the epochs (if there is a large gap increase between validation/training accuracy, you are starting to overfit your model). You can then use the gap info to stop your training. This is a version of what is known as early stopping (stop before you reach the minimum in your loss function).

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition to me seems completely correct.
But here is the caveat. The whole purpose of deep models is that they are "deep" (duh!!). So what happens is that your feature space gets exponentially larger as you grow your network.

**Here is an example to compare a deep model with a simpler mode:**

Assume you have a 10-variable data set. With a crazy amount of feature engineering, you might be able to extract 50 features out of it. Then if you run a traditional model (let's say a logistic regression), you will have 50 parameters (capacity in your word, or degree of freedom) to train.

But, if you use a very simple deep model with Layer 1: 10 unit, layer2: 10 units, layer3: 5 units, layer4: 2 units, you will end up with (10*10 + 10*10 + 5*2 = 210) parameters to train.

Therefore, usually when we train a neural net for a long time, we end of with a memorized version of our data set(this gets worse if our data set is small and easy to be memorized).

But as you also mentioned, there is no intrinsic reason why higher number of epochs result in overfitting. [Early stopping](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-stop-training-deep-neural-networks-at-the-right-time-using-early-stopping/) is usually a very good way for avoiding this. Just set patience equal to 5-10 epochs.